# Команда lea: Почему разные ответы получаются?

Tags: ассемблер

```
    .model flat 
    .code
public main
main proc
    ; здесь все четко
    mov     eax, 4292870144
    lea     eax, [eax+4294951040+4294967168]    

        ; и здесь все без нареканий
    mov     ebx, 4292870144
    add     ebx, 4294951040
    add     ebx, 4294967168

        ; НО ЗДЕСЬ МОЙ РАЗУМ ОСТАВЛЯЕТ МЕНЯ
    mov     esi, 4292870144
    mov     ecx, 4294951040
    mov     edx, 4294967168
    lea     ecx, [esi+ecx+edx]  ; **!!!здесь ошибка!!!** ecx <> eax = ebx


    xor eax, eax
    ret
main endp
end
```

Почему разные ответы получаются?

Comment: Вопрос задан не в том разделе.

Comment: Вероятнее всего, команда lea не выполняет сложение (напрямую), это команда вычисления еффективного адреса. Возможно при переходе через "границу" страниц или при переполнении она даёт  глюк.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, какие значения вы получаете, а какие ожидаете, и что за ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу команды вида `lea ecx, [esi+ecx+edx]`. Такая адресация недопустима, нельзя просто взять и сложить три регистра при помощи `lea`. Можно сложить смещение (число), базовый регистр, индексный регистр (при необходимости умноженный на множитель, являющийся степенью 2, максимум 8), т.е. что-то типа `lea ecx, [4292870144+ecx+esi*8]`.

Адресация вида `lea eax, [eax+число1+число2]` допустима только потому, что умный ассемблер два константных значения сложит на этапе компиляции, т.е. в результате будет просто `lea eax, [eax+число]`. Но fasm, например, не даст скомпилировать строку `lea eax, [eax+4294951040+4294967168]` из-за того, что полученное в результате сложения значение будет за пределами 32 бит (ошибка "value out of range"). nasm, похоже, в данном случае считает в пределах 32 бит (отбрасывает "лишние" старшие биты), поэтому ошибку не выдает и строку компилирует.

Вообще, команда `lea` изначально предназначена для адресной арифметики, а не для для произвольных вычислений. Я бы посоветовал изучить типы адресации, тогда будет понятно, что может вычислить `lea`, а что нет.

Answer (score 2):

Команда lea выполняет ограниченное число вариантов сложения и умножения. См. содержание квадратных скобок на картинке картинку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]